# How to remove Firefox Alert sound without lowering the system sound

Tags: sound, firefox

I am trying to remove or mute the Firefox sound (The BOOM sound and the Quick Drum sound) when:

- I try to close Firefox with multiple Tabs
- A download fails
- Any other case where that HORRIBLE heart killing sound pops up

I read several ways to do this but all involve either lowering the sound of firefox via the System Settings, or lowering the overall sound of the system, both of which I do not want to do. I just want to actually remove or disable the sound.

Note that I still want to get the warning but without the horrible sound.

PS - It is also my suggestion that that sound will make you go deaf and blind if not already. I think a cat dies every time that sound is heard and scares the hell out of me when I am working calm and quiet.

Comment: Is it possible to use [custom alerts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noise/) with FF? I don't see it in the options but if possible you could just copy the current ones, reduce volume 50% in Audacity, and re-add them. PS the cat thing is incorrect it's a baby seal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see three options:

1. Delete (move) the actual alert sound file, or lower its volume

   - It's `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-question.ogg`
2. Mute all alerts from Sound Settings:

   [image]
3. (for advanced users only): Add an AppArmor rule to Firefox's profile preventing it from accessing the `/usr/share/sounds` directory. (can add instructions if you need)

Comment: For #3, does this cause any secondary problems (like FF hanging)?

Comment: @izx - Can you provide the instructions for #3. I will try all 3 anyhow. For the #2 will this affect Skype alerts also?